# $f(x)=e^{|x|+x^2} +|x^2-1|$ is differentiable at $0,-1,1,2$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f(x)=e^{|x|+x^2} +|x^2-1|$ is differentiable at $0,-1,1,2$ ?

Could anyone just confirm me? I have checked once and got only not differentiable at $0$.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All we need is to look at $|x|,|x^2-1|.$

As you noticed, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ because of $|x|$, slope change abrupt.

Likewise, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=\pm 1$ because of $|x^2-1|$. see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%5E2-1%7C) slope changes abruptly.

However $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=2.$

Do you need  proofs for these?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f (x)$ is not differentiable at $0,-1, 1\,$ but $f (x)$ is differentiable at $2$.